# can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Tags: python, json

i'm trying to read multiple phone numbers from text file

```
import urllib.request
import json

#number = input("Phone number.\n(with country code): +")
with open('D:/num.txt') as json_file:
    number = json.load(json_file)

data = urllib.request.urlopen("").read()

parsed = json.loads(data)

print(json.dumps(parsed["data"], indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

program should read multiple phone numbers from txt file and display the result 
is it possible to read from pandas ?

Comment: It's very unclear what you need. Can you elaborate? Also title has nothing to do with the question so far.

Comment: @DanIftinca I'm trying to read multiple phone numbers, and passing it to data (which contain that link). the code is taking one number at a time but i need to process multiple numbers from stored text file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`number` is an `int`, you can't concat it to a `str`. Eithe cast it to `str`

```
urllib.request.urlopen("https://search5.truecaller.com/v2/search?q=" + str(number) + "&countryCode=&type=4&locAddr=&placement=SEARCHRESULTS,HISTORY,DETAILS&adId=&clientId=1&myNumber=lS59d72f4d1aefae62ba0c1979l_Dl7_DEj9CPstICL1dRnD&registerId=645710775")
```

Or if you are using Python 3 you can use f-Strings

```
urllib.request.urlopen(f"https://search5.truecaller.com/v2/search?q={number}&countryCode=&type=4&locAddr=&placement=SEARCHRESULTS,HISTORY,DETAILS&adId=&clientId=1&myNumber=lS59d72f4d1aefae62ba0c1979l_Dl7_DEj9CPstICL1dRnD&registerId=645710775")
```

Comment: Totally missed the concat in the url when reading the question.

Comment: @DanIftinca thanks, the  above code is working  but it taking only one number from text file its showing error as " { JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 13)} "  .